# JList toArray method - display different information about a single class in seperate JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, tostring

I have two JLists and an ArrayList of Items in my Main Class and my Player class

```
  private ArrayList<Item> allItems= new ArrayList<Item>();

  listItemsShop= new JList(allItems.toArray());

  listItemsInv= new JList(currentPlayer.getAllItems().toArray());
```

As most are probably aware, the toArray method returns the contents of my collection 'allItems" as an array. This enables it to be used in the JList component.

The JList component then calls on my Items class toString method and returns whatevers in that. e.g.

```
    @Override
public String toString() {
    return  name + "," + "$"+price;
}
```

This is fine for my first JList 'listItemsShop' but for my second JList I dont want to display the price. The second JList is an inventory so the Item has been purchased.. I would like to only display the Items name and maybe some other details such as damage amount or condition..

Does anyone know of a way to do to this? I have read of someone creating a duplicate class and overwriting the second classes toString method that way, this seems like a large redundancy though. If anyone knows of another way around this I'd love to hear from you.

Cheers

Comment: You want a [*Custom Cell Renderer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

Comment: @whiteElephant: because of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171083/is-there-such-thing-as-too-much-detail-in-questions/171084#171084), the first condition of asking question is: *Short*, read more on [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: So your saying I gave to much code? Its all relevant stuff to my question. Ive been down voted before for having not enough code.

Comment: Both cases are bad the first was too short and this one is too much description, sorry but I am gonna to tell you please be very specific and choose the shortest way for asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a JList. Instead use a JTable. Then you can control what columns you want to display. See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Sorry, I misread you question. As trashgod suggest, it's better to use cell renderers:

```
public class ItemCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   public static enum Type {SHOP, INVENTORY;}

   private Type type;

   public ItemCellRenderer(Type t) {
      super();
      this.type = t;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
      Item item = (Item) value;
      if (type == Type.SHOP) {
         label.setText(item.getPrice());
      } else if (type == Type.INVENTORY) {
         label.setText(item.getData());
      } else {
         label.setText(null);
      }
      return label;
   }
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
listItemsShop.setCellRenderer(new ItemCellRenderer(ItemCellRenderer.Type.SHOP));
listItemsInv.setCellRenderer(new ItemCellRenderer(ItemCellRenderer.Type.INVENTORY));
```

**OLDER**

I think it is better to delegate the string method to the inventory/shop instead of coding it in the item class. Like

```
class Inventory {
   public String toString(Item item) {
      return item.getName() + " " + item.getStats();
   }
}
```

and for shop

```
class Shop {
   public String toString(Item item) {
      return item.getName() + " $" + item.getPrice();
   }
}
```